# Не могу вывести отрицательные значения в Python

Tags: python

```
number = [1,2,-5,8,-9]
max = number[0]

for num in number:
    if max < 0:
        print(max)
    max+=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
number = [1,2,-5,8,-9]

lst_number = [x for x in number if x < 0]
print(lst_number)
```

Если список отдельно не нужен, а нужен только его вывод, можно так:

```
print([x for x in number if x < 0])
```

Если же нужен просто поэлементный вывод отрицательных элементов, можно так:

```
number = [1,2,-5,8,-9]

for num in number:
    if num < 0:
        print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(lambda x: x<0, number)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
number = [1,2,-5,8,-9] 
max = []

for num in number: 
   if num < 0: 
      print(num) 
      max.append(num))
```

Comment: max можно не использовать, если не требуется хранить отрицательных элементов в массиве

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.